# Getting incorrect date when converting epoch to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch, sql-timestamp

I have a timestamp in epoch format like this: `1551187548876`. If I convert this to a timestamp using https://www.epochconverter.com/, I get the correct time back.

However, if I convert it to time using PostgreSQL `to_timestamp`, I get the following:

```
select to_timestamp(1551187548876) from my_table;

51125-03-06 14:14:36+00
```

**Question**

How can I convert epoch `1551187548876` to a timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Divide by 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the epoch number you have is the number of *milli*seconds since the epoch, not the number of seconds, as customary.

Try dividing by 1000:

```
select to_timestamp(1551187548.876);

        to_timestamp        
----------------------------
 2019-02-26 14:25:48.876+01
(1 row)
```